# Build problems after updating Xcode 7.2 to 7.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, cocos2d-x

I have updated my Xcode version from v7.2 to v7.3.1 on Mac OS X v10.11.6 and I have an exiting project (Cocos2d-x game) I was working on. When I try to build the project I get this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/usr/lib/lazydylib1.o'
```

When I check that directory there is only iPhoneOS9.3.sdk and iPhoneOS.sdk.

What do I need to change to point my Xcode project to iPhoneOS9.3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the old SDK references from your build settings in xcode. Click your project > General > Linked Frameworks and Frameworks

Remove all the 9.2 versions and add their 9.3 counterparts using the + icon at the bottom.